# Why the following code gives "hello5" as output in C?

Tags: c

Follwing code in C gives the output "hello5" ...how?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
int f = fun();
printf("%d",f);
return 0;
}
void fun(){
printf("hello");
}
```

Comment: Read the man page for printf and all will be revealed.

Comment: @PaulR He is not returning from the function the behavior is undefined

Comment: Oh yes, it should be an int return on fun, but it's a dupe (many times over) anyway.

Comment: This code doesn't even compile in `gcc`.

Answer (score 2):

What you see is undefined behavior.

The value `f` is never initialized and you are printing uninitialized variable which will lead to undefined behavior.

`printf()` returns number of characters successfully printed out so the count here is 5(hello) for printing hello.

You need to return this value if you want then you have defined behavior because you are initializing the variable `f` in main()

```
int func()
{
  int j;
  j = printf("hello");
  return j;
}
```

Comment: but when i define the fun() before the main() function it gives an error..         #include<stdio.h>
void fun(){
 printf("hellobye");
}
int main(){
 int f = fun();
 printf("%d",f);
return 0;
}
can you explain plz ..

Comment: @RajeshSethi Yes the default return type for the function is `int` and since there is no forward declaration in the first case the compiler thinks the function will return int but in the second part when you move the fun() above main the compiler knows that the function will returns void and you are trying to assign this return value to some variable so it reports error

Comment: okk got it.. now in the original question when i vary the length of string in the printf() ..say printf("hellobye"); it gives 8 as output.. is the return value of printf() which is an integer is used as a default return value of the fun().. ?

Comment: @RajeshSethi You shouldn't rely on undefined behavior. You need to move your function above main and make the return type as int and you should `return` from the function which is a int value